# Error while installing google app sdk plugin inside Eclips Juno

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sdk, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

While installing Google App SDK plugin for Eclipse JUNO. It's giving me error .

While installing i have used "https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2" URL for SDK inside HELP -> Install NEW software Catagory ..

It's giving me following error .. here i have attached snapshot .. please take a look. and give me some solution for it ....

SCREENSHOT ----> http://imageupload.co.uk/files/t00ge7hr9k3xb5d4lwsl.png

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking the contact all update sites during install.